# Session not recognised on first attempt at logging in

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, safari

**Issue resolved** - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719452/1174295

--

I've come across a problem within (at least) Google Chrome and Safari.

Upon the first attempt at logging in, the user is not redirected. The session is created, but it is almost as if it is not detected, and takes the user back to the index page. Upon a second attempt, the correct redirect is issued and the user is taken to the correct page.

The script works fine in Firefox, and I have checked extensively to see if the correct data is being returned, which it is. I've searched and I've searched and I've searched, but unfortunately nothing of use has cropped up.

**Access.php - User logging in**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();


include_once('db.class.php');
include_once('register.class.php');
include_once('login.class.php');


$db = null;
$reg = null;
$log = null;


$db = new Database();
$log = new Login($db, null, null, null, null, null, null);


if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {    
    $log->redirectUser($_SESSION['login']);
}


include_once('includes/header.html');

?>

Some HTML...

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['logsub'])) {
        $db = new Database();
        $log = new Login($db, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

        $validation = &$log->validate();

        if(empty($validation)) {
            $log->redirectUser($_SESSION['login']);
        } else {
            echo "<div id='error'><div class='box-error'><p style='font-weight: bold'>The following errors occured...</p><ul>";

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($validation); $i++) {
                    echo "<li>" . $log->getErrorMessage($validation[$i]) . "</li>";
                }
            echo "</ul></div></div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Login.class.php - Login class**

```
// Validate the credentials given
public function validateLogin() {
    // Hash the plain text password
    $this->hashedPass = $this->hashPassword();

    try {
        $query = $this->dbcon->prepare("SELECT Login_ID, Login_Email, Login_Password FROM Login WHERE Login_Email = :email AND Login_Password = :pass");
        $query->bindParam(':email', $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':pass', $this->hashedPass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        $fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $this->loginid = $fetch[0];

        // If a match is found, create a session storing the login_id for the user
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $this->loginid;    
            session_write_close();
        } else {
            return LOG_ERR_NO_MATCH;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->dbcon->rollback();
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Fetch the customer ID
private function getCustId() {
    try {
        $query = $this->dbcon->prepare("SELECT Customer.Cust_ID FROM Customer JOIN Login ON Customer.Login_ID = Login.Login_ID WHERE Customer.Login_ID = :loginid");
        $query->bindParam(':loginid', $this->loginid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        $fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);     
        return $fetch[0];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->dbcon->rollback();
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Check the registration progress - are they verified? paid?
// This function is used elsewhere hence the $sessionid argument
public function checkRegistration($sessionid) { 
    $this->loginid = $sessionid;
    $this->custid = $this->getCustId();

    try {
        $queryVer = $this->dbcon->prepare("SELECT Cust_ID FROM Customer_Verify_Email WHERE Cust_ID = :custid");
        $queryVer->bindParam(":custid", $this->custid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $queryVer->execute();

        $queryFee = $this->dbcon->prepare("SELECT Cust_ID FROM Initial_Fee_Payment WHERE Cust_ID = :custid");
        $queryFee->bindParam(":custid", $this->custid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $queryFee->execute();

        // If a record exists in the verify table, return the value 1. This means the user has not yet verified their email.
        if ($queryVer->rowCount() == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            // If a record does not exist in the payment table, no payment has been made. Return 2.
            if ($queryFee->rowCount() == 0) {
                return 2;
            // Otherwise, email is verified and the payment has been made.
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->dbcon->rollback();
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Redirect the user accordingly
public function redirectUser($sessionid) {
    $this->loginid = $sessionid;    
    $logNum = $this->checkRegistration($this->loginid);

    if ($logNum == 0) {
        header("Location: fbedder/details.php", true, 200);
        exit();
    } else if ($logNum == 1) {
        header("Location: fbedder/verification.php", true, 200);
        exit();
    } else if ($logNum == 2) {
        header("Location: fbedder/payment.php", true, 200);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the site: fbedder/ -> I have set-up a test account with the credentials -> email: test@ / password: test123321

To reiterate, the problem exists only in Google Chrome and Safari (the Safari being on my iPhone) and lies purely within the logging in aspect. On the first attempt, the session will be ignored (it is created), and on the second attempt, the user will be redirected.

Any ideas? I've tried a multitude of possibilities...

-- **Edit** --

I know where the issue lies now.

When the redirect is called, it sends the user to the details.php page. However, this page contains the following snippet of code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location: fbedder/index.php");
}
```

Obviously what is happening, is that the session is not being detected / saved / "whatevered", and as a result is sending the user back to the index page. Is there are a way to ensure the $_SESSION is not effectively lost. I had read about this before posting here, and is why I inserted `session_write_close()`, but that doesn't seem to be doing the desired effect.

Comment: Take note: You cannot send headers after HTML code. For example, you cannot send `header("Location: xxx")` after you echo/print/have some HTML. It looks like you may have this. Look at Access.php in the second `<?php ?>` group

Comment: Maybe look at an `else` statement for your `if` block on `redirectUser`.  Perhaps not so much session related as `checkRegistration` not returning expected value?  In other words end of `redirectUser` should never be reached right?

Comment: ok - neither of these explain the issue being tied to specific browsers though.  You sure it does not happen in other browsers?  red herring or great clue...?

Comment: @UnholyRanger That had crossed my mind, but the fact that it works on the second attempt lead me to cross that problem out. I'll have a play with it anyway.

Comment: @ficuscr I appended several variables to a log file and all was as expected, and the correct statement was being issued, it just wasn't issuing. It works perfectly fine on Firefox (v. 18.0.1), but at least on Google Chrome (v. 24.0.1312.57 m) and Safari (iPhone version) it does not. The headache I see is that it works on the second attempt in these browsers. It's as if the session is lost

Comment: I just created a new file, access_comp.php which is pure PHP and contains the snippet after the HTML. The submitted form posts the data to this page and the result was still the same unfortunately, the redirect failed. Hmm...

Comment: No https in the mix?  www.jonline.me.uk vs jonline.me.uk?  Only thing that makes sense is what UnholyRanger said.  On the first attempt you set the session but then have output before the redirect.  On second attempt the session is set and you call the redirect *before* you have output.

Comment: Changing the url to http://jonline.me.uk appears to have fixed the problem (in Chrome), but now Firefox disagrees and spits out that the page isn't redirecting properly. Strange! And when you word it how you have with regards to the session, I'd agree that this is probably what is happening.

Comment: @ficuscr On reflection, I was under the impression `ob_start()` stored the contents in a buffer, allowing the headers to be set (or at least somewhere to that degree). Removing `if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ...` from the top of Access.php still produces the same error, so I'm lead to believe that this is no longer the issue. Any other ideas? Thanks so far either way!

Comment: It's definitely not to do with the headers, setting the redirect to http://www.google.co.uk works.

Comment: See my edit/update to the main body, I have found the ultimate cause, though how to resolve this I've no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diagnosing the problem being within the fact the $_SESSION variable was effectively being lost, I read up about the `session_write_close()` function and came across this comment:

> My sessions were screwing up because I had 2 different session IDs going at once:
>
> - 1 PHPSESSID cookie for domain.com
> - 1 PHPSESSID cookie for www.domain.com
>
> This fixed it:
>
> //At the beginning of each page...
>
> session_set_cookie_params  (1800,"/","domain.com");
>   session_start();

Source: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#84925

Setting the parameters resolved the issue.